# New to telegram bots

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm looking for a bot to obey users commands. For example, a member wants to learn more information about 'x', could that person type /x and then the bot answers with the explanation requested automatically?
Does that make any sense?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the common use case for bots (in messengers). See Wikipedia:

> A chatbot is a type of software that can automate conversations and interact with people through messaging platforms. Chatbots are used in dialog systems for various purposes including customer service, request routing, or information gathering. While some chatbot applications use extensive word-classification processes, natural language processors, and sophisticated AI, others simply scan for general keywords and generate responses using common phrases obtained from an associated library or database.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatbot)